# 'Value never used' changes to 'variable not initialized'

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings, delphi-10-seattle

If I compile the below code it gives a warning on line 1:

> value assigned to lTime never used*

But if I remove that line, I get a different warning on line 2:

> variable lTime might not have been initialized

Is the compiler missing something, or am I?

```
procedure TFormWebServices.RemoveOldReports;
var
  TSR       : TSearchRec;
  I         : Integer;
  lCutOff,
  lTime     : Int64;
  TSToDelete: TStringList;
  S,Msg     : String;
  E         : Exception;
begin
  lCutOff := DelphiToJavaDateTime(Now - cDefReportLifeMins/1440);
  I := FindFirst(FReportDir + '*.pdf',0,TSR);
  TSToDelete := TStringList.Create;
  while I = 0 do
  begin
    if (TSR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then 
    begin
      lTime := lCutOff;          // Line 1
      try
        lTime := StrToInt64(Copy(TSR.Name,1,pos('.',TSR.Name)-1));
      except
        on E:Exception do lTime := lCutOff;
      end;
      if lTime < lCutOff then    // Line 2
        TSToDelete.Add(TSR.Name);
    end;
    I := FindNext(TSR);
  end;
```

This is not a dupe of [Why is the Compiler warning that variable may not be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554857), because I assign `lTime` in the exception as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Compiler warning that variable may not be initialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554857/why-is-the-compiler-warning-that-variable-may-not-be-initialized)

Comment: It looks like a duplicate indeed.

Comment: Really, though, there's no need to use exception handling here.  The RTL provides a suite of `TryStrTo[x]` methods for exactly this purpose - much more efficient than letting the exception handler deal with it.  [TryStrToInt64 Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt64)

Comment: Just save yourself some trouble and use either TryStrToInt64, or StrToInt64Def.  Exceptions are expensive (and annoying while debugging)

Comment: On a side note, if you would remove line 1 AND remove the "on E:Exception do" in the exception block, you won't get a warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lTime := lCutOff;       
try
  lTime := StrToInt64(Copy(TSR.Name,1,pos('.',TSR.Name)-1));
except
  on E:Exception do lTime := lCutOff;
end;
if lTime < lCutOff then
  TSToDelete.Add(TSR.Name);
```

The compiler is correct to warn about this code. When you assign `lTime := lCutOff` on the first line, the value written in that assignment is never read.

However, when you remove the code things are less clear cut.

```
try
  lTime := StrToInt64(Copy(TSR.Name,1,pos('.',TSR.Name)-1));
except
  on E:Exception do lTime := lCutOff;
end;
if lTime < lCutOff then
  TSToDelete.Add(TSR.Name);
```

There are two scenarios to consider: an exception is not raised inside the `try/except` block, or an exception is raised there.

If no exception is raised then it is simple, `lTime` is assigned the result of `StrToInt64` and is therefore initialized before being read.

In an exception is raised, then `lTime` is not initialized inside the block. What happens next?

- If the exception derives from `Exception` (not compulsory) then it is caught and `lTime` is initialized.
- If the exception does not derive from `Exception` then it is not caught and `lTime` is never read.

Therefore, the compiler could infer all of that and therefore not issue an uninitialized variable warning. However, the compiler does not do flow analysis of that complexity, sadly. I believe that its logic runs like this:

1. An exception is raised before `lTime` is initialized, then
2. The exception could be caught, in which case
3. The variable `lTime` is then read, and still might be uninitialized.

In step 2 it ought to be able to realise that `lTime` is initialized but it simply does not perform such analysis. So whilst one could argue that the compiler could do better, you just have to accept this as a limitation of its analysis algorithms.

Having understood that we are left with the task of finding a way to write the code and avoid the warnings. We don't want to suppress the warnings, we just need to find a way to write the code so that it is both correct and free of warnings.

The way forward, in my view, is to recognise that exceptions are the wrong tool to use here. It is normal behaviour for this conversion to fail. You should write the code using conversion functions that don't raise an exception when they fail. For instance you could use one of the following options:

```
if TryStrToInt64(..., lTime) then
  if lTime < lCutOff then
    ....
else
  lTime := lCutoff;
```

Or:

```
lTime := StrToInt64Def(..., lCutoff);
if lTime < lCutOff then
  ....
```

Comment: Delphi XE compiler does not generate the false warning ''variable .. might not have been initialized' on this code.

Answer (score -1):

This is correct behaviour. The line 1 value will never be used since in the try/except you assign a new value without using the previous one, hence the warning.

if you remove the line you try to use the lTime variable outside a try/except block which may fail without actually setting a value to lTime

```
procedure TFormWebServices.RemoveOldReports;
var
  TSR       : TSearchRec;
  I         : Integer;
  lCutOff,
  lTime     : Int64;
  TSToDelete: TStringList;
  S,Msg     : String;
  E         : Exception;
   begin
   lCutOff := DelphiToJavaDateTime(Now - cDefReportLifeMins/1440);
   I := FindFirst(FReportDir + '*.pdf',0,TSR);
   TSToDelete := TStringList.Create;
   while I = 0 do
      begin
         if (TSR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then 
            begin
               lTime := lCutOff;          // Line 1
               try
                  lTime :=     StrToInt64(Copy(TSR.Name,1,pos('.',TSR.Name)-1));
               except
                  on E:Exception do lTime := lCutOff;
               end;
               if lTime < lCutOff then    // Line 2
                  TSToDelete.Add(TSR.Name);
            end;
         I := FindNext(TSR);
      end;
```

You could do this

```
procedure TFormWebServices.RemoveOldReports;
var
  TSR       : TSearchRec;
  I         : Integer;
  lCutOff,
  lTime     : Int64;
  TSToDelete: TStringList;
  S,Msg     : String;
  E         : Exception;
   begin
   lCutOff := DelphiToJavaDateTime(Now - cDefReportLifeMins/1440);
   I := FindFirst(FReportDir + '*.pdf',0,TSR);
   TSToDelete := TStringList.Create;
   while I = 0 do
      begin
         if (TSR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then 
            begin
               lTime := StrToInt64Def(Copy(TSR.Name,1,pos('.',TSR.Name)-1), lCutOff);
               if lTime < lCutOff then    
                  TSToDelete.Add(TSR.Name);
            end;
         I := FindNext(TSR);
      end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know there was also a StrToInt**64**Def

Comment: I disagree with paragraph 2. There is actually no circumstance, when line 1 is removed, where `lTime` can be read before it has been initialized.

Comment: The line 2 warning only occurs when line 1 is removed. Why is that incorrect?

Comment: As I said, there is no scenario whereby `lTime` can be accessed before it has been initialized. Or can you prove me wrong by demonstrating such a scenario?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan lTime could be accessed without being initialized in the situation where whatever is raised is not an Exception. (i.e. raise TObject.create). Now, we all know that won't happen in StrToInt64Def, but it is still a situation the compiler need to account for.

Comment: @KenBourassa No it could not because in that situation the exception would not be caught and so `lTime` would not be read. That's covered explicitly in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My bad...  We get to learn something new everyday.  Always thought try except block catched everything no matter what.  Good new is, I guess I can stop adding "else raise;" at the end of my "typed" except block.